# Как получить значение атрибута HTML элемента

Tags: vue.js

Необходимо получить значение `data-*` атрибута во Vue:

```
<select v-model="form.activewindow" name="activewindow">
  <option v-for="compare in compares" :value="compare.value" :data-price="compare.price">
      {{ compare.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Пробую так, но не выходит:

> priceActive = this.form.activewindow.getAttribute('data-price');

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ref. В шаблоне, например:

```
<div data-bullshit-attribute="hello, world!!" ref="div"></div>
```

В Коде:

```
const attrValue = this.$refs.div.getAttribute('data-bullshit-attribute');
```

Comment: а чтобы брать значения из select?

Comment: this.form.find(':data-price').text()

Comment: не знает такую функцию как find